# Induced homomorphism is injective

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, fibration

Let $\pi:M\longrightarrow N$ be a surjective submersion or fiber bundle(local trivialization) or fibration. Here $M$ and $N$ are manifolds. 
Why the induced homomorphism of first cohomology group $\pi^{*}:H^{1}(N)\longrightarrow H^{1}(M)$ is injective?

Is proposition correct for all case?

Comment: I have a suggestion. Don't change or strengthen the hypotheses on this question, as you did when you edited it after the answer of @TesmoAristide was posted. Instead, simply add a link to [your later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272651/fibration-with-t2?noredirect=1#comment6730205_3272651) where you asked it with stronger hypotheses.

Comment: @LeeMosher You are right.Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be a $p$-lens space i.e the quotient of $S^{2n-1}, n>1$ by the action of $\mathbb{Z}/p$, $H_1(L,\mathbb{Z})$ is not trivial implies that $H^1(L,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is trivial, but $H^1(S^3,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is trivial.

[Integral homology of lens space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499631/integral-homology-of-lens-space)

Comment: If M and N both compact and connected, What about this case?

Comment: The lens space and the sphere are compact and connected.

Comment: You mean for all case that is incorrect?

Comment: if $N$ is torus ie, there is a fibration M to $T^{2}$, is induced homomorphism is injective?

Comment: Yes, because it is a product, apply Kunneth.

Comment: Which is product? Total space or $T^{2}$?